# Argument of type '{ identifier: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I'm new on typescript, here i have been adding typescript to my project, getting this strange error: `No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error. Argument of type '{ identifier: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'. Type '{ identifier: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ConcatArray<never>': length, join, slice Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error. Argument of type '{ identifier: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray<never>'.ts(2769)`

my code where it is giving me that(reducers.ts):

```js
interface Update_AnalyserState {
  identifier: string;
}

const initialArticleState= {
  analysers: [],
};
export function articleReducer(
  state = initialArticleState,
  action: articleReducerAction
) {
  switch (action.type) {
   
    case ActionType.UPDATE_ANALYSER:
      return {
        ...state,
        analysers: state.analysers
          .filter(
            (a: Update_AnalyserState) =>
              a.identifier != action.payload.identifier
          )
          .concat(action.payload),
      };
       }
}
```

any help/suggestion with this ?

Comment: any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to debug from your example but I think the problem is this

```
const initialSiteArticleState = {
  analysers: [],
};
```

Your analyzers is an empty array type so it means it's `never[]`. So the result of the filter is going to be a `never[]`. So you will have to correctly type that `initialSiteArticleState`.

Something like

```
const initialSiteArticleState:{analysers: Update_AnalyserState[]} = {
  analysers: [],
};
```

Give it a shot. Here is also a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2BlJBTAggJ2WDWwyhSmxgF4YBvAKBhhTHQE8Jt8IAuGANoBdADQMAvgG4GDBJXwAzFMCoBVAA4ATCtgD6uNmk7cyO%20k3ibsYZArjd%200fAgDm08TNCRYUALbqaeERkdCxKAiISU0oAOlYOLh4YuzR5AAo0lF4NbUp9Q2N8aOwASmoAPi8IEBIYtBAXTJKSoA) that I tried to reproduce your code. If you hover on `tmp` you can see it's type `never[]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will need more information to help you, it's not clear to me what might cause that issue.

Comment: i got it working with your example but one question, as you can see in my interface 'interface Update_AnalyserState {
  identifier: string;
}
' i dont have analysers, so why that works with your way ?

Comment: With this `{analysers: Update_AnalyserState[]}` you are creating a new inline interface. This is where the `analysers` exists. So you are declaring that your `analyzers` in the `initialSiteArticleState` is going to be an array of `Update_AnalyserState` and not an empty array `never[]`.

Comment: could help with this also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69700957/type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-model-nodes-links