# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ model: { nodes: []; links: []; }; }'.ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, redux-toolkit

I'm new on typescript, here i have added types to a project of mine, it is giving me error on one of types at graph: "" : Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ model: { nodes: []; links: []; }; }'.ts(2322)

`The expected type comes from property 'graph' which is declared here on type 'InitialGraphArticleState'`

any help/suggestion is appreaciated.

```js
interface InitialGraphArticleState {
  graph: { model: { nodes: []; links: [] } };
  currentNode: string;
  currentLink: string;
  currentCameraNode: string;
  currentCameraLinks: [];
  floorplan: string;
}

const initialGraphArticleState: InitialGraphArticleState = {
  graph: "",
  currentNode: "",
  currentLink: "",
  currentCameraNode: "",
  currentCameraLinks: [],
  floorplan: "",
};

export function graphArticleReducer(
  state = initialGraphArticleState,
  action: graphArticleReducerAction
) {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `initialGraphArticleState` object, the property `graph` does not match the interface definition: You are basically a assigning a `string` to a property of type `{ model: { nodes: []; links: [] } }`.

You can either change the object initialization as follow:

```
interface InitialGraphArticleState {
  graph: { model: { nodes: [], links: [] } };
  currentNode: string;
  currentLink: string;
  currentCameraNode: string;
  currentCameraLinks: [];
  floorplan: string;
}

const initialGraphArticleState: InitialGraphArticleState = {
  graph: { model: { nodes: []; links: [] } },
  currentNode: "",
  currentLink: "",
  currentCameraNode: "",
  currentCameraLinks: [],
  floorplan: "",
};
```

Or update your interface definition to allow a `null` graph object and initialize to that instead:

```
interface InitialGraphArticleState {
  graph: { model: { nodes: [], links: [] } } | null;
  currentNode: string;
  currentLink: string;
  currentCameraNode: string;
  currentCameraLinks: [];
  floorplan: string;
}

const initialGraphArticleState: InitialGraphArticleState = {
  graph: null,
  currentNode: "",
  currentLink: "",
  currentCameraNode: "",
  currentCameraLinks: [],
  floorplan: "",
};
```

Considering how you are using the `graph` property in the reducer, I would advise the first solution, otherwise you need to check that the property is not null before trying to use its properties.